# QGIS Modeler Layer order

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

Is there a way to Order the way Layers are displayed when adding them to a process in the modeler?

I am trying to add 4 layers to a VRT process before using a Clip by polygon function and the problem I am having is this-

When adding the layers to the VRT process they are coming in as

```
Raster 1,
Raster 3 (optional),
Raster 4 (optional),
Raster2.
```

This is annoying as I would like them ordered 1,2,3,4 as layers 3  and 4 are optional and wont be used each time when the model is being used. I just can't find how to set which order they are asked for in the execution of the model.

Comment: Related to [Processing modeler Output Order](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/157702/processing-modeler-output-order?rq=1)